# Get content from txt file and put it in a list Flutter/Dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart, txt

this is my first question here on stackoverflow. Before i get into the question itself, i want to point out that i'm a beginner on Flutter and Dart and have no previous experience in mobile development.

Now, as the title says i'm having some issues while trying to extract the content of a text file and store the individual names inside the indexes of a list. The end goal of my application is to print a never ending list of these names, each separated to another by a comma. For example:

```
top model,
torcitóre,
torcolière,
tornitóre,
tosacàni,
tossicòlogo,
tour operator,
tracciatóre,
tranvière,
trattorìsta,
trattóre²,
trebbiatóre,
trecciaiòlo,
trevière,
tributarìsta,
trinciatóre,
trivellatóre,
truccatóre,
tubìsta,
turnìsta,
```

The text file, named `jobs.txt` contains more than a 1000+ italian job names. After several hours searching, all i have here is this (got from another user):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  try {
    final _jobs = File('jobs.txt');

    List<String> lines = _jobs.readAsLinesSync(encoding: ascii);
    for (var l in lines) print(l);
  } catch (Exception) {
    print(Exception.toString());
    
  }
}
```

`jobs.txt` is inside the same directory as the dart file, which is `bin`.

While trying to give the `_jobs` variable the relative path:

```
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'binjobs.txt' (OS Error: Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
, errno = 2)
```

With absolute path:

```
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:UsersUserDesktopdartdart_application_injobs.txt' (OS Error: La sintassi del nome del file, della directory o del volume non è corretta.
, errno = 123)
```

For reasons i don't know, if that even matters, in the path specified in the error message, the \ look like they don't even exist.

By the way, this is my project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig6UU.png)

If your solution includes the usage of the Future class or async-await keywords, i'll be thankful if you could explain me how they work.

**UPDATE: Look in the comments for the full solution to this issue. The verified answer isn't the full solution.**

Comment: you have to specify path name like asset/jobs.txt and make sure you have added folder in pubspec

Comment: How do i add a folder in pubspec? Currently i'm inside a dart-only project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an assets folder in your project, in your pubspec.yaml specify the asset (make sure it's in your assets folder, that the file exists and is readable)

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/jobs.txt
```

Now you can access your text file like so -

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/jobs.txt');
}
```

When the function returns your text, you can split it by commas and loop through all the jobs as you wish

Comment: After loading the file, how do i get it to be a string? I tried using the .then(), but i have no clue right now

Comment: String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/jobs.txt"); now data will contain the string value of the jobs.txt content.

Comment: I'm getting an error at ".of(context)", undefined. Is there any library i have to import?

Comment: Since comments have a char limitation, let me refer you to this resource, create a new sample dart file and add this code (with tweaking to your environment) - https://www.yourowncodes.com/how-to-read-content-of-text-file-from-assets-in-flutter/ it's very simple; btw your error is because your context is undefined (not sure where you added that line) but kindly refer to this URL above for me; once you get it once it'll resonate throughout everything you're doing

Comment: I'm getting an error accessing that page: "Error communicating with origin". Could you send me the code snippet, pasting it in a website like pastebin?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gku54YmQ check it out

Comment: Done, i'm able to read and display the file content on screen. The only thing is that i can't scroll through its content. But, that's about it for this question. Thanks!

Comment: Aye that would have to do with your container, whether your pushing the return to a view such as a SingleChildScrollView that's all UI debugging - most important part is, you figured out how to access the string from your text file :)

Comment: If that doesn't bother you, could you pick up again that code you gave me, and add some explanatory comments? I'd like to understand the code you gave in order to avoid this error again in the future

Comment: For the UI issue where you are unable to scroll? or for getting the text? I think getting the text is straight forward, you registered your jobs.txt asset in pubspec and in your dart class you loaded the asset - the container you returned your asset data to child: Text(dataFromFile), <-- should be in a scrollview, reason being it overflows a static position because you have so many items; you can also parse it into a list builder and add it to a listview :) - I recommend flutterawesome.com as a great learning resource

Answer (score 0):

try using rootBundle

```
  pubspec.yaml
      assets:
        - text_file/

  import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    try {
      return await rootBundle.loadString('text_file/four_words.txt');
    } catch (e) {
      throw (e.toString());
    }
  }
```